# My Macbook Air Battery Is not Charging and the Icon Shows Charging

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery, mojave

My MacBook Air does not charge sometimes. It shows a different battery icon and the battery does not charge. Previously I used to get rid of this by opening battery settings, upon opening the battery settings my Mac would charge smoothly again. But now this solution works no more and my Mac stops charging mysteriously. I think this is a software issue as I ran Mac Diagnostic and it showed me no hardware issues found.

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.

Status of the battery when it does not charge.
[image: When my Mac does not charge.]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What about the led charger color: green, orange or off? I used to have a charger with the led turned off, or green, so it wasn't charging (or randomly so). I ended up using another charger.

Answer (score 1):

First of all imo you should not provide hardware data of yr computer in plain site (and don’t get me wrong to say this). Its 101 infosec. 
So ...i would try this: 
1. backup my  (time machine & an external HD) -have all my accounts written down (iCloud-appleid- Gmail ets) just in case...
2. Delete all of it  . Restore it from backup. 
https://www.imore.com/how-to-prepare-mac-for-sale
So it’s:
        Step 1: Back up your Mac
        Step 2: Sign out of everything
        Step 3: Reformat your hard drive
        Reinstall a clean Mac operating system

Now if issue persists , I would take it to Genius Bar .
Hope to have helped you.